# ANT or MAVEN for my selenium project?

Tags: maven, ant, selenium-webdriver, maven-3

I'm developing a hybrid framework for GUI automation. I'm using TestNg. I'd like to use ANT / MAVEN. What are the factors that we need to take into account before we make the decision? I have read the difference between ANT and MAVEN online. I have a theoretical understanding of both. But practically how do i decide if ANT / Maven fits my project.Let us say that I choose ANT for my project.Is this a correct decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven can be considered as a successor for Ant. Maven also has the Surefire plugin for TestNG which provides very elegant TestNG test suite execution. Ant is older and while it is still used in a number of projects, it is rapidly losing ground to Maven. I used Ant for my very first TestNG project and since then moved on to Maven.

Dependency management in maven is easier and you can have several different project phases. Maven, IMHO, is easier to understand as well and updating dependencies and creating and importing modules is very easy. You can use either one to good effect for simple projects but if your project size if going to grow, you will want to use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is newer and the lingua franca. The simplest way to tell is the fact that far more open source Java projects (I don't know about closed source projects) have Maven support natively, and fewer have Ant support (notwithstanding plugins and other applications that make them both-way compatible). You can research this yourself.